# PHP MAIL Parse Error

Tags: email, php

Подскажите, почему и как исправить такую ошибку? PHP так норм работает, а если в консоли дать ссылку ему на файл с функцией mail(), у него parse error, хотя SendMail работает исправно

Comment: код ошибки в студию, и строчку где ошибка вышла )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опять зовём на помощь телепатов: Linux, да? Скрипт для консоли взят www-шный и в него не добавлшен шебанг (строчка такая, типа #!/usr/bin/php)?